# Non-invocable member 'Http SessionState.Timeout' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Email"] = "sssaundatti@gmail.com";
        Session.Timeout("200");
```

> Non-invocable member 'Http SessionState.Timeout' cannot be used like a method

```
    }
```

> How to solve this problem?

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Email"] !=null)
        {
            Email.Text = Session["Email"].ToString;

        }
        else
        {
            Email.Text = "Please Set Session";

        }
    }
```

Comment: `Session.Timeout = 200;`

Comment: To follow along with @JohnWu's answer, check out the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8.  `Timeout` is a property of `HttpSessionState`, not a method.  You *set* or *get* the value of a property, you don't "Invoke* (aka call) it.  Use the docs, they are your friend

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear: "This is not a function. Stop trying to use it like one."

Without even looking at the class, I can guess that Timeout will be a field or property. While properties are just Syntax sugar for get/set function pairs, they are used like any normal field in 95% of all cases. That is what the Syntax sugar is there for.

I am also going out on a guess that Timeout is not a string property/field. So the string `"200"` would be the wrong input anyway.

So in both cases the proper line is:

`Session.Timeout = 200;`

Edit:
Confirmed. [It is a property. And a Integer one.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout)